# Equivalence of two definitions of $\sup$

Tags: real-analysis

so I am trying to learn real analysis, and I'm following two textbooks so I can cross-reference each other. However, I see two definitions of $\sup$, and I wonder how to prove that they're equivalent.

First definition:

$\alpha = \sup A$ if

- $\alpha$ is an upper bound of A i.e. $\forall x \in A, x \leq \alpha$
- If $\gamma < \alpha$ then $\gamma$ is not an upper bound of A i.e. $\exists x \in A, x > \gamma$

Second definition:

$\alpha = \sup A$ if

- $\alpha$ is an upper bound of A i.e. $\forall x \in A, x \leq \alpha$
- If $\gamma$ is an upper bound of A, $\gamma \geq \alpha$

Thank you. <s>Real analysis is kinda hard</s>

Comment: The second line of the first definition is the opposite of the second line of the second definition.

Comment: ^^ contrapositive

Comment: The second bullet of the second definition should state that $\gamma\geq\alpha$.

Comment: thanks for the clarification! :)

Comment: Oh my god, I see it now... I was staring at the symbols for too long, but looking at the words made a lot more sense - (not $A \implies B$) = ($not B \implies not A$)! Thank you haha.

Comment: exactly! In mathematics there are many times that you must see the meaning behind the symbols!

Comment: Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more formal proof!

Let the definition of $supA$ be the first one. If $γ > a$, then $\forall x,\space γ > a >= x$. So $γ > a$ is an upper bound as second definition states.

Let the definition of $supA$ be the second one. Suppose (in order to reach a contradiction) that $γ < a$ and at the same time $γ$ an upper bound. Then by second definition (which we took into consideration) it must be $γ < a$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: I believe your first point should be $\gamma \geq \alpha$, which was a mistake in my original problem, at least mentioned by the comments. Anyways, thank you for this :) I need to read more formal proofs haha.

Comment: There is no sense on taking $γ = a$. We just try to find out what is happening with $γ \ne 0$. Yor welcome anyway!

Comment: True true. Also I realised I didn't accept your answer haha.

Comment: The method I proposed by contrapositive in comments is just a quick approach to that problem! So if you want to be mathematically correct you use contradiction as above!

Comment: As far as the proofs is concerned, you don't have to read more proofs! Just as I said see the meaning behind the symbols, even if the meaning is hard to visualize!